# Expo Go Project - expo-image-manipulator

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, expo

I have one project that going to use TensorFlow and expo go. However, every time it process the picture taken from camera or system, it can't process and have this log. The model can be load nicely, taking picture and pick picture from the file system still able, but if i want to predict, it output this error at the log

```
LOG  Classifying image...
LOG  Model and image are available
LOG  Preprocessing image...
ERROR  Error preprocessing image: \[TypeError: Cannot read property 'manipulateAsync' of undefined\]
ERROR  Error classifying image: \[TypeError: Cannot read property 'manipulateAsync' of undefined\]
```

I have try to check the version of expo-image-manipulator and install it back, but occur this problem. If i install it back, the @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl keep on show out and make the expo apps cannot be run nicely. Anyone have some idea how to fix these?

```
Android Bundling failed 175ms
Unable to resolve "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl" from "node_modules@tensorflow\\tfjs\\dist\\tf.node.js"
```

Code as below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TouchableOpacity,
StatusBar,
Image,
Modal,
TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import \* as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import \* as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { bundleResourceIO } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import { ImageManipulator } from 'expo-image-manipulator';  
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

const DiagnoseScreen = () =\> {
const \[model, setModel\] = useState(null);
const \[imageUri, setImageUri\] = useState(null);
const \[prediction, setPrediction\] = useState('');
const \[modalVisible, setModalVisible\] = useState(false);
const navigation = useNavigation();

const modelJSON = require('../model/model.json');
const modelWeights = require('../model/weights.bin');

const loadModel = async () =\> {
try {
await tf.ready(); // Wait for Tensorflow.js to be ready
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights));
console.log('Model loaded!');
return model;
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error loading model:', error);
return null;
}
};

useEffect(() =\> {
const loadModelAsync = () =\> {
loadModel()
.then(loadedModel =\> {
setModel(loadedModel);
})
.catch(error =\> {
console.error('Error loading model:', error);
setModel(null);
});
};
loadModelAsync();
}, \[\]);

const openCamera = async () =\> {
const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Permission denied');
      return;
    }
    
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
      maxWidth: 224,
      maxHeight: 224,
      allowsEditing: true,
    });
    
    console.log('Image Capture Result:', result);
    
    if (!result.canceled && result.assets.length > 0) {
      const capturedImageUri = result.assets[0].uri; // Get the image URI
      setImageUri(capturedImageUri); // Set the image URI
      console.log('Image URI:', capturedImageUri);
      setPrediction(''); // Reset prediction when a new image is taken
      classifyImage();
    } else {
      console.log('Image capture was cancelled or no image selected.');
    }

};

const pickImage = async () =\> {
try {
const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
quality: 1,
maxWidth: 224,
maxHeight: 224,
allowsEditing: true,
});

      if (!result.canceled && result.uri) {
        // Image was selected successfully
        setImageUri(result.uri);
        setPrediction(''); // Reset prediction when a new image is selected
        classifyImage();
      } else {
        console.log('Image selection was cancelled or no image was selected.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error selecting image:', error);
    }

};

const handleRefresh = () =\> {
setImageUri(null);
setPrediction('');
};

const classifyImage = async () =\> {
try {
await tf.ready();

      console.log('Classifying image...');
    
      if (model && imageUri) {
        console.log('Model and image are available');
    
        const imageTensor = await preprocessImage(imageUri); // Wait for preprocessing
        console.log('Image Tensor Shape:', imageTensor.shape);
    
        const predictionTensor = model.predict(imageTensor);
        const predictionData = await predictionTensor.data();
        console.log('Prediction Data:', predictionData); // This will show the prediction values
        // Process predictionData to get the actual prediction
    
        // Set the prediction result
        setPrediction('Your Prediction Here');
      } else {
        console.log('Model or image not available');
        setPrediction('Error: Please take the photo again');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error classifying image:', error);
      setPrediction('Error: Image classification failed');
    }

};

const preprocessImage = async (imageUri) =\> {
console.log('Preprocessing image...');

    try {
      const image = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
        imageUri,
        [{ resize: { width: 224, height: 224 } }],
        { format: 'jpeg' }
      );
    
      const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image).toFloat();
      const offset = tf.scalar(127.5);
      const normalized = tensor.sub(offset).div(offset);
    
      console.log('Image preprocessing complete.');
      console.log('Image Tensor Shape:', normalized.shape);
      return normalized.expandDims();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error preprocessing image:', error);
      // Handle the error here, e.g., set an error state or throw an error
      throw error;
    }

};

const takePhotoAndClassify = async () =\> {
try {
const result = await openCamera();

      if (result && !result.canceled && result.assets.length > 0) {
        setImageUri(result.assets[0].uri);
        setPrediction(''); // Reset prediction when a new image is taken
        classifyImage();
      } else {
        console.log('Image capture was cancelled or no image selected.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error capturing image:', error);
    }

};

return (
\<View style={styles.container}\>
\<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" /\>
\<View style={styles.header}\>
\<Ionicons
name="arrow-back"
size={24}
color="#FFFFFF"
style={styles.backButton}
onPress={() =\> navigation.navigate('Home')}
/\>
\<Text style={styles.headerTitle}\>Diagnose\</Text\>
\</View\>
{imageUri ? (
// Render the captured image and prediction when imageUri is not null
\<View style={styles.capturedImageContainer}\>
\<Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={styles.capturedImage} /\>
{prediction && (
\<View style={styles.predictionContainer}\>
\<Text style={styles.predictionText}\>
Prediction: {prediction}
\</Text\>
\</View\>
)}
\</View\>
) : (
// Render the camera snap range when imageUri is null
\<View style={styles.cameraSnapRangeContainer}\>
\<View style={styles.cameraSnapRange}\>
\<Text style={styles.cameraSnapText}\>Camera Snap Range\</Text\>
\</View\>
\</View\>
)}
\<TouchableOpacity style={styles.takePhotoButton} onPress={takePhotoAndClassify}\>
\<View style={styles.cameraButtonBorder}\>
\<Ionicons name="camera" size={48} color="#4F4F4F" /\>
\</View\>
\<Text style={styles.takePhotoText}\>Take Photo of Your Tongue\</Text\>
\</TouchableOpacity\>

      {/* Button to select a photo from the gallery */}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pickPhotoButton} onPress={pickImage}>
        <View style={styles.cameraButtonBorder}>
          <Ionicons name="image-outline" size={48} color="#4F4F4F" />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.pickPhotoText}>Select Photo from Gallery</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    
      <View style={styles.dividerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.divider} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.noticeButton, { flex: 0.35 }]} onPress={handleRefresh}>
          <Text style={styles.noticeButtonText}>Reset</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.buttonSpace} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.noticeButton, { flex: 0.35 }]}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.noticeButtonText}>Notice</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {prediction && (
        <View style={styles.predictionResultContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.predictionResultText}>
            Prediction Result: {prediction}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(false);
        }}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
          <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
            <View style={styles.modalContent}>
              <Text style={styles.noticeText}>
                Please do not clean your tongue before and during taking the tongue photo for better accuracy.
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.closeButton}
                onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
              >
                <Text style={styles.closeButtonText}>Close</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Modal>
    </View>

);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#F5F9FF',
},
header: {
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#3477eb',
height: 60,
paddingTop: 10,
},
headerTitle: {
fontSize: 24,
color: '#FFFFFF',
fontWeight: 'bold',
},
backButton: {
position: 'absolute',
left: 10,
color: '#FFFFFF'
},
cameraSnapRangeContainer: {
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 20,
},
cameraSnapRange: {
width: 260,
height: 200,
backgroundColor: '#D4F0EE',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
borderRadius: 15,
},
cameraSnapText: {
fontSize: 20,
color: '#4F4F4F',
fontWeight: 'bold',
},
takePhotoButton: {
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 10,
},
cameraButtonBorder: {
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: '#4F4F4F',
borderRadius: 50,
padding: 10,
},
takePhotoText: {
fontSize: 16,
color: '#4F4F4F',
},
space: {
height: 20,
},
divider: {
borderBottomColor: '#4F4F4F',
borderBottomWidth: 2,
width: '80%',
marginBottom: 20,
alignItems: 'center',
},
buttonRow: {
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
refreshButton: {
backgroundColor: '#D4F0EE',
paddingVertical: 10,
borderRadius: 10,
marginRight: 10,
},
buttonText: {
color: '#4F4F4F',
fontWeight: 'bold',
textAlign: 'center',
},
noticeButton: {
backgroundColor: '#4F4F4F',
paddingVertical: 10,
borderRadius: 10,
},
noticeButtonText: {
color: '#FFFFFF',
fontWeight: 'bold',
textAlign: 'center',
},
modalBackground: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
},
modalContent: {
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
padding: 20,
borderRadius: 15,
width: 300,
},
noticeText: {
fontSize: 16,
color: '#4F4F4F',
marginBottom: 10,
},
closeButton: {
backgroundColor: '#D4F0EE',
padding: 10,
borderRadius: 10,
alignItems: 'center',
},
closeButtonText: {
color: '#4F4F4F',
fontWeight: 'bold',
},
dividerContainer: {
alignItems: 'center',
marginBottom: 20,
},
resultText: {
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: 'bold',
marginTop: 10,
textAlign: 'center',
},
resultUnderline: {
width: 40,
height: 2,
backgroundColor: '#4F4F4F',
alignSelf: 'center',
marginTop: 5,
},
capturedImageContainer: {
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 10,
},
capturedImage: {
width: 150,
height: 150,
borderRadius: 10,
resizeMode: 'cover',
},
buttonSpace: {
width: 10,
},
predictionResultContainer: {
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 10,
},
predictionResultText: {
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: 'bold',
color: '#4F4F4F',
marginTop: 5,
},
pickPhotoButton: {
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 10,
},
pickPhotoText: {
fontSize: 16,
color: '#4F4F4F',
},
});

export default DiagnoseScreen;
```